# NSCollectionView contained within an NSPopover not showing content

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, popover, collectionview

I have a situation where I have a subclassed `NSCollectionView` as a subview in a `NSViewController` that displays its content perfectly when used as a view in a storyboard.

When I try to use the same controller class as a `contentViewController` for an `NSPopover` window, the window loads as expected; all controls render and behave as expected - **with the exception** of the subclassed `NSCollectionView`.  That view remains blank regardless of how (and when) I try to load its contents.

The same delegates and data sources are used for both scenarios.  As a storyboard segue view, they work.  As a popover they don't.  I am sure I am missing something, I just don't know what.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Environment:

- Mac OS: 10.13.5
- XCode: 9.3.1
- Swift: 4.1

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question - just in case someone was stuck like I was.  It turns out to be a simple omission on my part: Encapsulating the subclassed NSCollectionView in a NSScrollView - yep, it was that simple.

Thanks to **thierryH91200** and his RetailStoreUISwift example: https://github.com/thierryH91200/RetailStoreUISwift for THE answer.  After careful examination, the only difference in our two implementations was the scrollview container.  Once I added that, the popover worked as expected.

On to the next challenge ...